# Implement boolean function with given components

Tags: digital-logic, design, boolean-algebra

I have to implement these functions using the following components only

$$F_1(A,B,C) = AC + BC'$$
$$F_2(A,B,C) = AC + B'C'$$
$$F_3(A,B,C) = A'B + AB'$$

Components given:

1. 1:4 DeMux with active high enable - 1 No.
2. 2:4 Decoder with active low enable - 1 No.
3. 8:3 Encoder with active low enable - 1 No.

I thought of using DeMux as another decoder and use Encoder for taking OR of product terms, but I can't seem to get it.

It would be great if someone could help.

**UPD** My work:
[image]

Comment: Could you show what you have tried. And if it is a homework question, please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @JonathanG I have updated the question. It's not a homework question. It was in my final exams this semester in digital design course.

Answer (score 0):

I will update my answer along the day.
But first, how does the demux work? As the enable is always high, depending on the select lines the data in will be output on one (1) of the four (4) output lines.[image: Demux]

Not my finest drawing, but please continue with a correct 1:4 Demux. If you get stuck again, I will try updating my answer again.